# NUnit: How can I determine in [TearDown] if the actual [Test] was successful or not?

Tags: nunit

How can I determine in `[TearDown]` if the actual `[Test]` was successful or not using `NUnit`?

I would like to leave (Selenium drived) Chrome browser window open in `[TearDown]` if the particular `[Test]` was not successful. In case of success the window can be closed.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a particularly elegant way to achieve this, but by using the [method of attribute counting described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/429e79b2-6841-4e18-b3f4-dc1f50eedf15/how-can-we-get-the-test-status-in-nunit) and by incrementing a counter every time a test passes, you can then compare the result in your teardown.

Disclaimer: Note that this will only work if all tests in the fixture are run (since all `Test`s are counted - e.g. using the R# test runner on individual `Test` cases will fail miserably). It will also fail if you have `Ignore`d one or more tests in the fixture, as the counts will be out.

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private static int testsPassed = 0;

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
         // use reflection to find all tests in this fixture
        var totalTests = GetType()
            .GetMethods()
            .Count(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(
               typeof (TestAttribute), false).Count() > 0);

        if (testsPassed == totalTests)
        {
            // All good - can close the driver
            // seleniumDriver.Quit()
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void FailedMethod()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1,2);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref testsPassed);
    }

    [Test]
    public void PassMethod()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref testsPassed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I think [TearDown] will run after all tests multiple times... I would like to detect that particular test was succesful or not.

Comment: If you just want to check a single `[Test]` then just have a bool `isSuccessful` which is set and detected in the same way above?

Comment: Yea, it is. It is more simple what I thought. I was looking for some built in facility don'know why, and that blocked my brain. Thx

Comment: I guess the issue preventing a more elegant solution is that it is the  TestRunner which retains the overall status of the tests - different test runners (NUnit, R#, NUnitConsole, etc) might have different implementations, and it would be unusual to couple the TestFixture back to the runner in this way in any event.

Answer (score 0):

One option is writing a [custom NUnit `EventListener` addin](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.6.3). With this you could get notified about a test failing or succeeding and increment some counters.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `TestContext`. Since this is an old question I am not entirely sure whether this was possible in the past.

Example to exclude code from running when a test failed:

```cs
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status != TestStatus.Failed)
{
    // Code here is skipped if test failed
}
```